# how to call global variable inside another scope Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i get the value of the global variable inside a scope .
If i have the same name variable present in same scope .

```
<script>
var number =2;

var fun= function(numbs){
    console.log(number);
    //here it displays 2

    var number =numbs;
    console.log(number);
    //here it  displays 3


    console.log(number);
    //how do i get value of global variable here
}

fun(3);
</script>
```

Comment: IMHO it is poor form to use the same variable name in different scopes and try to reference the parent(s) scope(s). use `var numbers = numbs;` instead!

Comment: Did you run this before posting? The first line (`// here it displays 2`) actually displays `undefined` due to variable hoisting.

Answer (score 6):

you should be able to call

```
window.number
```

A global variable is really just a property of the window object.

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
console.log(window.number);
```

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Global_variables) :

> Global variables
>
> Global variables are in fact properties of the global object. In web
>   pages the global object is window, so you can set and access global
>   variables using the window.variable syntax.

But you shouldn't have to do this. If you need to go around shadowing, you have a design problem and you should probably fix it.